# What should be the POST JSON body for ManyToMany mapping in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

Say I have two entities User.java and Topic.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_USR")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="USR_ID", updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name="FST_NM", nullable=false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LST_NM")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="CREATED_DT")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createdDate;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="T_USR_TOPIC",
            joinColumns= { @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID") },
            inverseJoinColumns= { @JoinColumn(name="TOPIC_ID") })
    private Set<Topic> topics;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_TOPIC")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Topic {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="TOPIC_ID",updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private Long topicId;

    @Column(name="TOPIC_TAG")
    private String topicName;

    @Column(name="TOPIC_DS")
    private String topicDesc;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="topics")
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

I already have few entries in T_TOPIC table say 
TOPIC_ID | TOPIC_DS | TOPIC_TAG 
1        | UI       | Angular 
2        | Java     | Spring

I want to register a new user. But how do form the JSON body?
Should it be like

```
{
"firstName": "Myname",
"lastName": "LastName",
"email": "example@example.com",
"interests": [1,2]
}
```

Request Object.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserRequest {

    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty
    private String firstName;

    @Email
    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty
    private String lastName;

    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty
    private String email;

    @JsonProperty("interests")
    Set<Long> topics;

}
```

Also, is it good idea to use bidirectional ManyToMany Mapping?

Comment: what are `interests`?

Comment: interests are the topics which i user will provide at the time of registering.

Comment: EDIT 1:- Added request object UserRequest.java in question.